# WSO2 ESB EI611 registry based values for configuration from Tooling

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

Am able to define registry based values in EI611 Management Console and use in Inbound endpoint or Proxy Service (via Tooling).

```
<parameter key="conf:/repository/FileLocation" name="transport.vfs.FileURI"/>
<parameter key="conf:/repository/FileMoveAfterFailure" name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure"/>
<parameter key="conf:/repository/FilePattern" name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern"/>
<parameter key="conf:/repository/FileMoveAfterProcess" name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess"/>
```

How to define registry resources from Tooling and deploy it as part of CAR and define/modify values in Management Console?

I created a registry resource in DS380 tooling and did not know what type to select, hence selected "datamapper" and gave "gov" with a name. Then, resources editor opened and I cannot do anything further. The registry is saved as

> .dmc

file and cant proceed further.

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Create Maven Multimodule Project, then add Composite Application Project, then add Registry Resource Project. After, you can add resource and edit then in IDE. One you are done open Composite Application find registry resource and change role to Enterprise Integrator.

Export Compositor App Project car file, deploy on server and you will see resources in server registry.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how do I add the key-value pair(name=value) in the registry resource? that's the only part, where the IDE or docs is not helpful.

Comment: Add xml snippet <props><key1>value1</key1><key1>value1</key1></props> as xml entry. Inject it into property, then extract value then needed